# Obtener valor de textbox JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo la siguiente funcion

```
    function reporte() {

          var string_request;

          Riesgo = document.forms.form1.Riesgo.options[document.forms.form1.Riesgo.selectedIndex ].value;
          Emisora = document.getElementById('Emisora').value;

         string_request = "reporte.asp?Riesgo="+Riesgo+"&Emisora="+Emisora;

        string_request = string_request.replace(/ /g,"%20");            
        parent.reporte.document.location=string_request;
}
```

Pero Emisora me lo envia vacio, no obtiene el valor que ingreso en el textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como obtener los valores de un textbox en JS:

```html
<html>

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>javascript - Obtener el valor de un input type=text de varias maneras</title>

    <script>

        function capturar() {

            // obtenemos e valor por el numero de elemento

            var porElementos = document.forms["form1"].elements[0].value;

            // Obtenemos el valor por el id

            var porId = document.getElementById("nombre").value;

            // Obtenemos el valor por el Nombre

            var porNombre = document.getElementsByName("nombre")[0].value;

            // Obtenemos el valor por el tipo de tag

            var porTagName = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;

            // Obtenemos el valor por el nombre de la clase

            var porClassName = document.getElementsByClassName("formulario")[0].value;



            document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = "Por elementos: " + porElementos + 
            "<br>Por ID: " + porId + 
            "<br>Por Nombre: " + porNombre + 
            "<br>Por TagName: " + porTagName + 
            "<br>Por ClassName: " + porClassName;
        }

    </script>



    <style>
        form {
            width: 250px;
            height: 180px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 10px;
        }
    </style>

</head>



<body>

    <h1>Obtener el valor de un input type=text de varias maneras</h1>

    <form id="form1">

        Nombre:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="nombre" value="jose" id="nombre" class="formulario">



        <p>
            <input type="checkbox" name="acepto" id="acepto" class="formulario_check"> Acepto el contrato</p>



        <p>Deacuerdo: Si
            <input type="radio" name="deacuerdo" value="si"> No
            <input type="radio" name="deacuerdo" value="no">
        </p>



        <p>

            <select name="seleccion" id="seleccion" class="formulario_select">

                <option value="1">primera</option>

                <option value="2">segunda</option>

            </select>

        </p>

    </form>

    <input type="button" value="obtener el nombre" onclick="capturar()">

    <div id="resultado"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Con **Javascript**

```
var Emisora = document.getElementById('Emisora').value;
```