# document,getelementby() me regresa nodelist

Tags: javascript, html

Saludos Espero estén bien! tengo un trabajo de la universidad y me he encontrado con este problema al probar la pagina y darle al botón de Mostrar solo me muestra `[object HTMLInputElement]` *undefined* Pero Quiero obtener los valores es decir, si en Nombre pongo Pedro, quiero que me Muestre Pedro y no [object NodeList] como puedo hacerlo? Aquí esta el código HTML y el Script

```js
var clientes = new Array();

function Guardar() {
  Nombre = document.getElementsByName('Nombre');
  Apellido = document.getElementsByName('apellido');
  Cedula = document.getElementsByName('Ced');
  Email = document.getElementsByName('Email');
  Direccion = document.getElementsByName('dir');
  Telefono = document.getElementsByName('telefono');
  Membresia = document.getElementsByName('membresia');
  Pago = document.getElementsByName('pago');
  clientes[clientes.length] = new Array(Nombre, Apellido, Cedula, Direccion, Telefono, Membresia, Pago);

}

function Mostrar() {
  lista = document.getElementById('Lista')
  contenido = ""
  for (x = 0; x < clientes.length; x++) {
    nombre = clientes[x][0]
    apellido = clientes[x][1]
    cedula = clientes[x][2]
    email = clientes[x][3]
    direccion = clientes[x][4]
    telefono = clientes[x][5]
    membresia = clientes[x][6]
    pago = clientes[x][7]






    contenido = contenido + "<div>" + nombre + " " + apellido + " " + cedula + " " + email + " " + telefono + " " + membresia + " " + pago + "</div>"
  }

  Lista.innerHTML = contenido;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Registro Gym el Sayajin</title>
</head>
Gimnasio El Sayajin

<body>
  <form action="" name="formulario" method="get">
    Nombre:<br>
    <input type="text" name="Nombre" maxlength="30" class="campo" id="name" placeholder="Nombre aqui" required>
    <br> Apellido:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="apellido" maxlength="30" class="campo" placeholder="Apellido aqui" required>
    <br> Cedula o pasaporte:<br>
    <input type="text" name="Ced" class="campo" placeholder="identificacion" required><br> Email
    <br>
    <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Correo electronico" required><br> Direccion: <br>
    <input type="text" name="dir" class="campo" placeholder="Direccion" required> <br> Telefono:
    <br>
    <input type="number" name="telefono" class="campo" placeholder="Contacto" required><br> Tipo de membresia: <br>
    <input type="radio" name="membresia" class="campo" value="Standar" required>Standar
    <input type="radio" name="membresia" class="campo" value="Gold" required>Gold
    <input type="radio" name="membresia" class="campo" value="Sayajin" required>Sayajin<br> Metodo de pago: <br>
    <input type="radio" name="pago" value="Efectivo" class="campo" required> Efectivo
    <input type="radio" name="pago" value="Tarjeta" class="campo" required> Tarjeta<br>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Guardar" onclick="Guardar();">
    <input type="button" value="Mostrar" onclick="Mostrar()">
    <input type="reset" id="btn3" value="Limpiar">
    <br>
    <div id='Lista'> Clientes Guardados</div>
  </form>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el HTML donde tienes al elemento `Lista`  que estás seleccionado por el id? Y dinos de qué se trata el problema. En tu pregunta no hay nada más que un bucle, además incompleto... ¿? ¿Qué intentas hacer realmente? ¿Dónde muestra `muestra [object HTMLInputElement] undefined `?

Comment: Aquí esta!  <div id='Lista'> Clientes Guardados</div>

Comment: Pon el HTML completo y el Javascript completo, o al menos el bloque erróneo. Aclara la pregunta editántola, puedes pulsar aquí [edit], para hacerlo. Y comprueba que no haya elementos con el mismo id  `Lista`. Gracias.

Comment: Puede que agregando value funcione? Intenta esto: lista=document.getElementById('Lista').value <- de esto hablo

Comment: Acabo de editar y agregar el HTML y el Javascript, Disculpen los inconvenientes con la falta de información anterior, espero puedan ayudarme!

Comment: El tema está en `Nombre = document.getElementsByName('Nombre')[0].value;`, es algo parecido a https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/77873/81450 o https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/174160/81450 , el ByName trae varios con el mismo name y genera un array (nodelist) lo más común es en checkboxes o radiobuttons

Answer (score 1):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

Una forma de simplificar tu código sería mediante el uso de [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Usando_Objetos_FormData). Creas una referencia al formulario y luego obtienes sus datos mediante el método [`entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries).

```js
function Mostrar() {
  var formElement = document.getElementById("formulario");
  var formData = new FormData(formElement);
  var divLista = document.getElementById("Lista");
  var txtDiv = "";
  for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    txtDiv += `${pair[0]}: ${pair[1]}<br />`;
  }
  /*Se modifica el elemento una sola vez, no dentro del bucle*/
  divLista.innerHTML = txtDiv;

}
```

```html
<form action="" id="formulario" method="get">
  Nombre:<br>
  <input type="text" id="Nombre" name="Nombre" maxlength="30" class="campo" id="name" placeholder="Nombre aqui" required>
  <br> Apellido:
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="apellido" maxlength="30" class="campo" placeholder="Apellido aqui" required>
  <br> Cedula o pasaporte:<br>
  <input type="text" name="Ced" class="campo" placeholder="identificacion" required><br> Email
  <br>
  <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Correo electronico" required><br> Direccion: <br>
  <input type="text" name="dir" class="campo" placeholder="Direccion" required> <br> Telefono:
  <br>
  <input type="number" name="telefono" class="campo" placeholder="Contacto" required><br> Tipo de membresia: <br>
  <input type="radio" name="membresia" class="campo" value="Standar" required>Standar
  <input type="radio" name="membresia" class="campo" value="Gold" required>Gold
  <input type="radio" name="membresia" class="campo" value="Sayajin" required>Sayajin<br> Metodo de pago: <br>
  <input type="radio" name="pago" value="Efectivo" class="campo" required> Efectivo
  <input type="radio" name="pago" value="Tarjeta" class="campo" required> Tarjeta<br>
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Guardar" onclick="Guardar();">
  <input type="button" value="Mostrar" onclick="Mostrar()">
  <input type="reset" id="btn3" value="Limpiar">
  <br>
  <div id='Lista'> Clientes Guardados</div>
</form>
```

---

#### Limitaciones

Dado que es una funcionalidad relativamente nueva, `FormData` no es soportado por algunos navegadores antiguos ([ver tabla de compatibilidad en `caniuse.com`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2)). Si tu programa está destinado a un amplio rango de usuarios de navegadores muy antiguos entonces lo puedes hacer por elemento.

**Recomendación:** Para obtener los valores de cada `input` la forma más directa de hacerlo es alcanzando el elemento por su `id`, para ello deberás darle un `id` y luego en Javascript hacer esto:

```
Nombre=document.getElementById('Nombre');
```

Actualmente estás usando `document.getElementsByName()` pero este método te devuelve un nodelist de los elementos y no es más complicado sacar el valor de allí.